# How to redirect and/or delay depending on referrer?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, referrer

I want to allow traffic to my site only from a certain referring URL like "example.com/123". I want the rest of traffic to be redirected to the same referring URL after a particular delay, say 1 or 2 minutes. I want the traffic 
that comes from example.com/123 not to be referred anymore.

I thought of using something like this but I have no clue how to edit to meet my requirements:

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("/site1.com/",$referrer)) {
      header('Location: http://www.customercare.com/page-site1.html');
} elseif (preg_match("/site2.com/",$referrer)) {
      header('Location: http://www.customercare.com/page-site2.html');
} else {
      header('Location: http://www.customercare.com/home-page.html');
};
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have something in your php script that affect the header of the **page**, and not the header of the actual server response.

So in the part of the script that generates the header of your pages, you need something like this:

```
<!-- this is the header of your page -->
<head>
  <title>Your Title</title>
  <?php
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    // if referer isn't from example.com/123 we setup a redirect
    if ( !strstr($referrer, '://example.com/123') )
       print ('<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="60; URL=http://example.com/123">\n');

    ?>
  <!-- maybe some other stuff -->
</head>
```

So if the referer *isn't* from `http://example.com/123`, then this line will be inserted into the header:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="60; URL=http://example.com/123">
```

which tells the browser to redirect to the URL (in this case `http://example.com/123`) after 60 seconds.