# how to setup redirects based on referrer for individual wordpress post in a wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

hello everyone newbie here. i would like to set up a referrer redirect for my word press blog like this. i only want people refereed from a particular link like example.com/444 to have access to that post without being redirected .  the rest traffic i would like to send them back to example.com/444

so to summarize

visitors from example.com/444 goes to post  no action needed

visitors from other othersites.com goes to post i would like to redirect them after a set time to  example.com/444

also i would like the redirect command to eliminate the back or undo action as if the traffic click back button in the browser they will return back to my post  and will be referred from  example.com.

example.com contains a set of actions the user has to complete in order to gain access to my post. after completing those action the user will be redirected to the post

i just want them to be redirected to my post only after completing the instruction on example.com

thanks you for listening

Comment: Isn't this pretty much the same thing as the question you asked just a little while ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229923/how-to-redirect-and-or-delay-depending-on-referrer

Comment: nope mate i need a soloution for individual post the solution u posted wont work with each individual post of wp also i don't want traffic to click the back button of browser and be redirected to my site

Comment: i only want the traffic to gain access to my site after completing the instruction in example.com. traffic to example.com gets redirected automatically after they have completed some instruction on that page

Comment: http://toomanysecrets.com/redirect-based-referer/

Comment: that wont do as i need it for specific posts

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to remind you that basing on referrers is really bad idea. People can just strip them (some antiviruses do that) or even use plugin that is doing that.